# Java "Content not allowed in prolog.”

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am writing a client that can reserve slots, view available slots, view slots you've booked and cancel reserved slots. My code for works for everything but reserving slots.

The below is code for reserving a slot.

```
      while(hotelBooked == false && bandBooked == false)
      {
          // This works
          xmlString = XMLRequest.availability(requestID, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
          ArrayList<String> availSlots = checkAvailiabilityOrBookings(xmlString);
          for(int i = 0; i < availSlots.size(); i++)
          {
              TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
              System.out.println("availSlots.get(" + i + "): " + Integer.parseInt(availSlots.get(i).trim()));

              // generate a unique ID based off time
              requestID = genRequestID();
              System.out.println("REQUESTID" + requestID);

              //Something goes wrong around here
              xmlString = XMLRequest.Reservation(requestID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, 134);
              // breaks in this method
              hotelBooked = reserveSlot(xmlString, hotelNum);

              if(hotelBooked == true)
              {
                  bandBooked = reserveSlot(xmlString, bandNum);
                  if(bandBooked == false)
                  {
                    requestID = genRequestID();
                    System.out.println("REQUESTID " + requestID);
                    xmlString = XMLRequest.cancel(requestID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, Integer.parseInt(availSlots.get(i).trim()));
                    cancelSlot(xmlString, hotelNum);
                  }// if
                  else
                  {
                      requestID = genRequestID();
                      System.out.println("REQUESTID" + requestID);
                          xmlString = XMLRequest.bookings(requestID, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        bookedSlots = checkAvailiabilityOrBookings(xmlString);
                        System.out.println("1st time - Booked slots:");
                        System.out.println(bookedSlots.toString());
                      break;
                  }
              }// if
```

The below is the method it breaks in

```
// reserve a slot
public static Boolean reserveSlot(String xmlString, String hotelOrBand) {
    System.out.println("Entered reserveSlot");
    Response recMsgOutput;
    PutMethod putMethod;
    boolean booked = false;

try {

    if(hotelOrBand.equals(String.valueOf(3010)))
    {
        putMethod = putMethodHotel;
    }
    else
    {
        putMethod = putMethodBand;
    }

  /*
   * Set the request's entity (body).
   */
    System.out.println("Set the request's entity (body)");
    RequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity(xmlString);
    putMethod.setRequestEntity(entity);

  /*
   * Set the put method's headers
   */
    System.out.println("Set the put method's headers");
    putMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    putMethod.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");

  /*
   * Create a client and the execute the put method.
   */

       System.out.println("Create a client and the execute the put method.");

       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
       int responseCode = client.executeMethod(putMethod);

       while(responseCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        client = new HttpClient();
        responseCode = client.executeMethod(putMethod);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
       }// while

      if (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        System.out.println("Message uri: " + Response.getMsgURI(putMethod.getResponseBodyAsString()));

        String [] message = Response.getMsgURI(putMethod.getResponseBodyAsString()).split("/");

        String msgNum = message[message.length - 1];

        String recMsgArg = "http://jewel.cs.man.ac.uk:" + hotelOrBand + "/queue/msg/" + msgNum + "?username=0ih058&password=4UhMf9";

        System.out.println("recMsgArg " + recMsgArg);

        String [] recMsgArgArray = new String[1];

        // Send requests to ClientRecMsg
        recMsgArgArray[0] = recMsgArg;
        System.out.println("recMsgArgArray " + recMsgArgArray[0]);
        recMsgOutput = ClientRecMsg.main(recMsgArgArray);

        Matcher matcher1 = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(recMsgOutput.toString());
        matcher1.find();
        int responseNum = Integer.valueOf(matcher1.group());
        System.out.println("num: " + responseNum);

        if(responseNum == 200)
            booked = true;

    } else if(responseCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
      System.out.println("Error code:" + responseCode);
      System.out.println("Error message:" + putMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
}//try
```

Outputs this

```
availSlots.get(4): 135
REQUESTID 1584934385
Entered reserveSlot
Set the request's entity (body)
Set the put method's headers
Create a client and the execute the put method.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
uk.ac.manchester.cs.comp28112.lab2.ParseException
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.comp28112.lab2.Response.getMsgURI(Response.java:179)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.comp28112.lab2.ClientReserve.reserveSlot(ClientReserve.java:527)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.comp28112.lab2.ClientReserve.reserveRequest(ClientReserve.java:164)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.comp28112.lab2.ClientReserve.main(ClientReserve.java:77)
```

The XML for reservation is the code below

```
    static public String Reservation(String request_id, String username,
            String password, int slot_id) throws RequestException {
        try {
            XMLRequest.createBuilder();

            Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
            Element reserve_element = document.createElement(RESERVE_ELEMENT);
            document.appendChild(reserve_element);

            Node id_element = document.createElement(REQUEST_ID_ELEMENT);
            id_element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(request_id));
            reserve_element.appendChild(id_element);

            Node username_element = document.createElement(USERNAME_ELEMENT);
            username_element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username));
            reserve_element.appendChild(username_element);

            Node password_element = document.createElement(PASSWORD_ELEMENT);
            password_element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(password));
            reserve_element.appendChild(password_element);

            Node slot_id_element = document.createElement(SLOT_ID_ELEMENT);
            slot_id_element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Integer(
                    slot_id).toString()));
            reserve_element.appendChild(slot_id_element);

            return XMLRequest.toString(document);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RequestException(e);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RequestException(e);
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            throw new RequestException(e.getException());
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            throw new RequestException(e);
        }
```

Below is the method for Response.getMsgURI()

```
    static public String getMsgURI(String xmlString) throws ParseException {

        try {
            Response.createBuilder();
            InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));

            Node node = (Node) msgIdXPathExpression.evaluate(source, XPathConstants.NODE);

            return node.getTextContent();

        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            throw new ParseException();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new ParseException();
        }
    }
```

Below is the output for putMethod.getResponseBodyAsString()

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></body></html>
```

I've think it's something to do with making multiple xml requests in the same method because when I make the reservation request first it runs fine but when I try to make another xml request immediately after that gets stuck as well.

Sorry for including so much code, help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: The "prolog" is the `<?` part of the XML document. Your XML seems to be malformed; that's what you need to post.

Comment: Since the error occurs inside the `Response.getMsgURI()` method, don't you think showing us that method might be relevant too, in addition to the String returned by the `putMethod.getResponseBodyAsString()` call? But then again, once you see the returned String, you'll likely see why that doesn't parse as XML, and the method code might be irrelevant. But, how would we know, since we can't see either.

Comment: Sorry about that I'm new to this and I feel like I'm posting tons of code, I didn't want to post more than necessary.

Comment: The main thing to understand is that "content not allowed in prolog" generally means that you have supplied something to an XML parser that does not start with "<". Sometimes it's because the file is empty, sometimes because it's not XML at all, sometimes it's because there's something before the "<" - perhaps an innocent newline character, perhaps (and this might be the case here) some HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to reuse putMethod objects, I needed to create a new one everytime I made a request. I don't know why this is though.